# If I can't nest anchor tags how do I create a a clickable item with a link in it

Tags: html, nested, anchor

I'm working on a large list of items. Each item in the list is clickable. However, I want a link on each list item. Is there a way to get around nesting anchor tags? When I tried to put an anchor tag in another IE didn't like that

Here's an example:

```
<li>
    <a>
        <a>link to something</a>
   </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I don't understand where the nesting comes in.  Can you show us an example markup?

Comment: Please show us code because we are not mind readers.

Comment: you don't have to be a mind reader. you just have to understand simple html

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to nest anchor tags, just put them inside your list items.

For example:

```
<li>
  <a></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

If that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks for the response. but what if I want my whole list item to be clickable?

Comment: Anchors are [not allowed to be nested](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2). If you want an entire list of links clickable, I'd use JavaScript [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick) event handler (or jQuery's [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)). I can provide more info if that's what you're looking to do.

Comment: thanks, I actually just did that and it seemed to work. I replaced my anchors with spans and add onClick events to those.

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of wasting your time making 's around the whole thing make the list like sc davis has done and in your css add this code > Cursor:pointer;